# Can we simulate FPGA board?

Tags: fpga, simulation

As a part of my curriculum, I am required to implement a project on FPGA. However, even the cheapest available boards are out of my reach (blame currency conversion !) and besides, even if I buy one, it would be lying useless thereafter.

So I wish to know whether I can simulate a real FPGA to get an '*all virtual solution*' ? If yes, do mention some softwares for the same.

In other words, I should be able to write verilog or systemVerilog code in some software, verify and test the code, and finally upload the code. Then I should be able to do all the stuff which I would normally do on a real FPGA like interfacing displays, keyboards etc. and verify that my design does work on real boards. Just this time, it would be within a simulation environment, much like we have simulators like MultiSim and Tina, where we can simulate hardware.

If we cannot, is there some other way by which I could possibly build FPGA design without having a real FPGA ?

Comment: Lattice do FPGA dev boards starting at under $30. You can implement VGA output with simple R-2R DAC on a piece of prototype board. If you need something more sophisticated, try asking for a loan of a dev board from your local Altera or Xilinx distributor.

Comment: @scary_jeff. Thats what I dont want to do (buy a board). And thats precisely why I mentioned 'currency conversion' ; otherwise people would start advising me to "Get a real board" :/

Comment: Just trying to help, since from the answers, what you want does not exist. You could always sell the board afterwards on ebay, and is a board that's cheaper than a text book really out of reach for an EE student? There's also the loan avenue; I've had expensive boards on loan before.

Comment: @scary_jeff: I guess you ain't seen the Eastern-economy textbook prices. Makes every US student jawdrop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need real interaction at real speed, then no there is no alternative. You can get quite creative with the testbenches, but if you need to send to a display then you're not going to be able to do that in software.

In some ways, FPGA *is* the simulator you're asking for; it's a simulation of an ASIC.

(If it's part of the curriculum it *really* ought to be provided by the course! Usually as a loan.)

Comment: Actually Altera has something called 'virtual fpga' but I couldnt find much info about it. I thought maybe there's something like that that would fulfil my needs. See -> http://newsroom.altera.com/press-releases/nr-soc-vp.htm . The language here is too technical for a noob like me. So maybe theres already something like this which I dont know of ? (I came to know of it from an electronics magazine, but besides this there was no more info provided)

Comment: That seems to be describing a simulation of the ARM core, with the capacity to connect to a simulation of the rest of the FPGA.

Comment: So does that mean simulation is possible ? To again quote the article from that magazine--"Announced in February 2015,
Altera and Mentor Graphics have
teamed up together to provide vir-
tual platforms that contain simula-
tion models of ARM processor sub-
systems featured in Altera’s SoC field
programmable gate array (FPGA)
families. This simplifies embedded
software development and reduces
the need for expensive hardware by
enabling large development teams to
perform application development and
software regression testing in a vir-
tual environment based on the chip. Is there...

Comment: ...something you know of like this ?

Comment: That's the kind of simulation you ruled out in the other answer. The Altera tools will let you simulate in software, but when doing so you cannot interact with real hardware.

Comment: (Unless I've misunderstood your comment about "logic functioning" versus "real functioning"?)

Comment: To clarify again : By interacting with real hardware in simulation (like those typical arduino sketches which show wiring and breadboard etc). Say, I'm building a system where I need to display characters which I type on keyboard (both are interfaced to fpga). I should be able to do this in software and see the results, rather than conventional waveforms in modelsim. (Its just a very basic example). Or am I misinterpreting this 'virtual fpga' thing ?

Comment: The simulation necessarily is much slower than the real thing. So your simulated keyboard interface can't talk to a real keyboard. This is what I meant by clever testbenches: you could have the simulation software detect keypresses and turn them into a stream of PS/2 or USB transactions at simulation speed. I had a simulator once which used Linux TUN/TAP to speak to real Ethernet by doing exactly that.

Comment: The Altera simulator does simulate the FPGA. But it doesn't simulate anything outside the FPGA. I think that's what you're missing.

Comment: (Presumably you can't use the Arduio sketches to interact with a real breadboard without actually possessing an Arduino either?)

Comment: Arduino sketch example was to just explain what i meant by interacting with real hardware in simulation. As far as the altera simulator is concerned, if it cant simulate beyond fpga, i dont think its better than real fpga either. I think I'll settle with conventional waveforms then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are talking about is having a [Test Bench](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_bench), a virtual environment used to verify a design. It can be done with any simulation software, like Multisim.

You can either code a virtual approximation of what your inputs and outputs are in Multisim/etc. and have your FPGA simulation interact with it, if you're lucky this may already exist and you just have to find it.

Comment: nope. I know about test benches. By test benches, I would only be able to verify logic functioning, whereas I wish to verify the real functioning ie how will my design behave if it interacts with a real display, real keyboard etc. (And I'm sure you mean Modelsim, not multisim ; both are different)

Comment: Real functioning, as in emulating the real world? So you want a software that can do circuit analysis on top of a behavioral simulation based on systemVerilog code? So that you can, say, monitor the drive strength of the I/O pins on the FPGA? And you may need other emulators for a display and keyboard?

Comment: sort of. Although my aim is to just verify functioning not go into that level of detail as to what the drive strength is..etc